# Can a commercial pilot with MPL , obtain PPL for general aviation in the UAE?

Tags: commercial-aviation, general-aviation

Is it possible for an airline pilot in case he would like to fly GA aircraft like c152/172 obtain the PPL license without going through the whole process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note: You did not specify a country. I will answer for EASA.*

You don't need to obtain a PPL, you may use the MPL (Multi-Crew Pilot Licence) if you fulfill the requirements. From [EASA Part-FCL](https://www.easa.europa.eu/sites/default/files/dfu/Part-FCL.pdf) (emphasis mine):

> **FCL.405.A MPL — Privileges**
>
> (a) The privileges of the holder of an MPL are to act as co-pilot in an aeroplane required to be operated
>   with a co-pilot.
>
> (b) The holder of an MPL may obtain the extra privileges of:
>
> (1) **the holder of a PPL(A)**, provided that the requirements for the PPL(A) specified in Subpart C are met;
>
> (2) a CPL(A), provided that the requirements specified in FCL.325.A are met.
>
> (c) The holder of an MPL shall have the privileges of his/her IR(A) limited to aeroplanes required to be
>   operated with a co-pilot. The privileges of the IR(A) may be extended to single-pilot operations in
>   aeroplanes, provided that the licence holder has completed the training necessary to act as PIC in
>   single-pilot operations exercised solely by reference to instruments and passed the skill test of the
>   IR(A) as a single-pilot.

You can find the requirements of Subpart C in the same [PDF](https://www.easa.europa.eu/sites/default/files/dfu/Part-FCL.pdf) on page 145f.

Comment: Would someone please define "MPL"?  (specifically, the "M"...)

Comment: MPL stands for Multi pilot License.

Comment: @Bianfable regarding the country lets say it's in United Arab emirates.

Comment: @MichaelHall Done.

Comment: @IslamAlmaghraby I'm sorry, I don't know about the rules in the UAE. Feel free to edit your question accordingly, maybe someone else will answer.

Comment: @Bianfable Thanks.